# How to conditionally merge two data frame efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to assign respective schedule no and trip no for every GPS packet based on the GPS time stamp. How can I do this efficiently since I have nearly a million GPS packets from various devices?

I didn't find any optimal way. I am now running loop across all the rows and compare its time-stamp with all the intervals in the schedule, route no table and attach the matching schedule numbers to each GPS packets.

GPS data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
gps_df = pd.DataFrame({'Device':[1,1,2,2,3,3,3],'time-stamp': ['6:00:00','7:00:30','12:12:12','13:13:13','20:15:10','22:16:10','22:18:23']})
```

Schedule data frame: \n

```
schedule_df = pd.DataFrame({'Device'    :[1,    1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  3,3,    3],
'schedule'  :['A1','A1','A2','A2','B1','B2','B2','C1','C2','C3'],
'route no'  :[1,    2,  1,  2,  1,  5,  6,  1,  1,  2],
'start time' :  ['6:00:00','7:00:01','8:30:00','10:00:00','12:00:00','14:00:00','16:00:00','20:00:00','21:00:00','22:00:00'],
'end time'  :['7:00:00','8:30:00','9:30:00','12:00:00','13:00:00','16:00:00','20:00:00','21:00:00','22:00:00','23:00:00']})
```

I would like to get the output like this:

```
gps_df = pd.DataFrame({'Device':[1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
                   'time-stamp':['6:00:00','7:00:30','12:12:12','13:13:13','20:15:10','22:16:10','22:18:23'],
                    'schedule': ['A1','A1','B1','Na','C1','C3','C3'],
                    'route':    [1, 2,  1,  'Na',1, 2,  2]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
cols = ['Device', 'schedule', 'route','timestamp']
df = df2.merge(df1, on='Device')
df = df.loc[df.timestamp.lt(df.end_time) & df.timestamp.gt(df.start_time), cols]\
       .set_index(['timestamp','Device'])\
       .reindex(index=df1.set_index(['timestamp','Device']).index)\
       .reset_index()

print(df)
  timestamp  Device schedule  route
0  06:00:01       1       A1    1.0
1  07:00:30       1       A1    2.0
2  12:12:12       2       B1    1.0
3  13:13:13       2      NaN    NaN
4  20:15:10       3       C1    1.0
5  22:16:10       3       C3    2.0
6  22:18:23       3       C3    2.0
```

---

Or:

```
df = df.loc[df.timestamp.between(df.start_time,df.end_time), cols]\
       .set_index(['timestamp','Device'])\
       .reindex(index=df1.set_index(['timestamp','Device']).index)\
       .reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
import pandas as pd

```
gps_df = pd.DataFrame({'Device':[1,1,2,2,3,3,3],'time-stamp': ['6:00:00','7:00:30','12:12:12','13:13:13','20:15:10','22:16:10','22:18:23']})
schedule_df = pd.DataFrame({'Device'    :[1,    1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  3,3,    3],
'schedule'  :['A1','A1','A2','A2','B1','B2','B2','C1','C2','C3'],
'route no'  :[1,    2,  1,  2,  1,  5,  6,  1,  1,  2],
'start time' :  ['6:00:00','7:00:01','8:30:00','10:00:00','12:00:00','14:00:00','16:00:00','20:00:00','21:00:00','22:00:00'],
'end time'  :['7:00:00','8:30:00','9:30:00','12:00:00','13:00:00','16:00:00','20:00:00','21:00:00','22:00:00','23:00:00']})
print(gps_df)
print(schedule_df)
gps_df = pd.concat([gps_df, schedule_df],sort=True)
gps_df = gps_df.drop('end time', axis=1)
print(gps_df)
```

**Output**

```
   Device time-stamp
0       1    6:00:00
1       1    7:00:30
2       2   12:12:12
3       2   13:13:13
4       3   20:15:10
5       3   22:16:10
6       3   22:18:23


   Device schedule  route no start time  end time
0       1       A1         1    6:00:00   7:00:00
1       1       A1         2    7:00:01   8:30:00
2       1       A2         1    8:30:00   9:30:00
3       1       A2         2   10:00:00  12:00:00
4       2       B1         1   12:00:00  13:00:00
5       2       B2         5   14:00:00  16:00:00
6       2       B2         6   16:00:00  20:00:00
7       3       C1         1   20:00:00  21:00:00
8       3       C2         1   21:00:00  22:00:00
9       3       C3         2   22:00:00  23:00:00


      Device time-stamp schedule route
0       1    6:00:00       A1     1
1       1    7:00:30       A1     2
2       2   12:12:12       B1     1
3       2   13:13:13       Na    Na
4       3   20:15:10       C1     1
5       3   22:16:10       C3     2
6       3   22:18:23       C3     2
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the response.
But could you explain me how to get the desired output from this.
pd.DataFrame({'Device':[1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
                   'time-stamp':['6:00:00','7:00:30','12:12:12','13:13:13','20:15:10','22:16:10','22:18:23'],
                    'schedule': ['A1','A1','B1','Na','C1','C3','C3'],
                    'route':    [1, 2,  1,  'Na',1, 2,  2]})

Answer (score 0):

You can try using numpy arrays. I've omitted some code to initialize the additional output columns you want to add to your GPS dataframe, but nonetheless the idea is to create a 2-D array where the intersection of the AND logics produce a truth table that maps matches by device ID and time within the range such that "i" is the corresponding row index in the GPS df and "j" is the corresponding row index in the Schedule df.

```
gpsd = GPS_df.Device.values
schedd = Sched_df.Device.values

gpst = GPS_df.timestamp.values
tl = Sched_df.start_time.values
th = Sched_df.end_time.values

i, j = np.where((gpsd[None].T == schedd) & 
                (gpst[None].T >= tl ) &
                (gpst[None].T <= th))
GPS_df.loc[i,'schedule'] = Sched_df.loc[j,'schedule']
GPS_df.loc[i,'route'] = Sched_df.loc[j,'route']
```

Comment: What does gpst[None].T do? When I try to execute this code it's throwing an error : cannot compare none type with datetime .(in the np.where line)